# Javascript: Enable 2 textbox simultaneously, once checkbox click

Tags: javascript

I have a question about my code below :

```
<input id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="alamatCat" 
       onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox3', 'textBox4')"> OT Date
</td>
<td>
From <input  id="textBox3" type="text" name="alamat" disabled="disabled"> 
To <input id="textBox4" type="text" name="alamat" disabled="disabled">
```

I want 2 textbox enable simultaneously if checkbox clicked.

Have any suggestions ?

revision :

how if i have the js below :

```
<script language="javascript">
function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID)
{
     document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(isChecked){
    document.getElementById('textBox3').disabled = isChecked ? "" : "disabled";
    document.getElementById('textBox4').disabled = isChecked ? "" : "disabled";
}

<input id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="alamatCat" 
       onchange="foo(this.checked);" />
```

**Note that inline code is deprecated.**

You can use `addEventHandler` instead:

```
document.getElementById('myCheckBox').addEventHandler('change', foo);
```

And change foo to:

```
function `foo`(){
    var disableAttribute = this.checked ? "" : "disabled";
    document.getElementById('textBox3').disabled = disableAttribute;
    document.getElementById('textBox4').disabled = disableAttribute;
}
```

Just note that for `IE` < 9 you need to use `attachEvent` read more on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Comment: How if I have the JS like this : <script language="javascript">
    function enableDisable(bEnable, textBoxID)
    {
         document.getElementById(textBoxID).disabled = !bEnable
    }
</script>

Comment: Since inline code is deprecated I would suggest attaching the event handler in a `<script>` tag via `element.addEventHandler('onchange', foo);`.